# How to convert selenium webdriver xpath value into css

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath, webdriver

The current code has long HTML Xpath values that need to be converted & shortened to a css value:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/button")).click();
```

Comment: So, what is your problem? Do get an error message?

Comment: this is not a good xpath to begin with, it should be something like `//form[identify form here]//button[identify button here]`, and it has no eought information to convert it to CSS selector. Change this xpath to use `@id`, `@class` or other unique attributes first.

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML so we can help you determine the CSS selector. Some CSS references that may help you: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors, https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/button")).click();
```

- You could possibly have chosen a better xpath expression than this one above. What you have done (without looking at the actual HTML code) is you have written down the complete xpath, is it possible to make it **shorter / more robust**?

Consider the following example:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">
    <body class = "question-page new-topbar">
        <div id="notify-container"></div>
            <div id="topbar-wrapper"></div>
                <button id="button1"></button>
    </body>
</html>
```

You want to click on `button1`, you can find it using the complete xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/div/button")).click()
```

or you can find it using xpath along this element's other attributes, in this case, its id.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='button1']")).click()
```

or as you wanted, you can use CSS selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('button[id='button1']')).click()
```

If you want us to help you with converting your xpath into css selector, you will need to copy and paste your html code in your question as well. Without looking at the actual code, we can not be 100% sure.

You may find the following link useful when trying to convert xpath into css selector. 
https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/

Comment: If you have an ID, you can just use `By.id("button1")` instead of the CSS selector.